# Have a problem with execution of instruction

Tags: debugging, assembly, gdb

This is disassembled code:

```
enter code here
7cda:   55    push %ebp
7cdb:   89 e5 mov  %esp,%ebp
7cdd:   57    push %edi
7cde:   56    push  %esi
7cdf:   53    push  %ebx
```

And this is instruction execution in gnu disassembler:

```
=> 0x7cda:  push   %ebp
0x00007cda in ?? ()
(gdb) 
=> 0x7cdb:  mov    %esp,%ebp
0x00007cdb in ?? ()
(gdb) 
=> 0x7d30:  add    $0x10,%esp
0x00007d30 in ?? ()
```

My question is there are many instruction in between address **0x7cdb - 0x7d30** without any jump instruction it is executing it leaving many instructions in between.

Comment: Which gdb command do you execute?  If you hit enter, this re-executes the previous command, but you do not specify which one it is.

Comment: ni command in  gdb

Comment: This skips function calls, including to inlined functions.  Try `stepi`.

Comment: @fuz: `ni` skips inlined functions?  That would explain it, but is not what I'd have expected!  Seems undesirable to me.  I guess it only happens when GDB actually has source line-number info, otherwise it would just have to look at the next instruction to see if it's a `call` or not.

Comment: @PeterCordes It is possible that `ni` just checks if the stack pointer has been manipulated and goes to the next instruction with the same stack pointer value as the previous one on `push`.

Comment: @fuz: Pretty sure that's not the case; this question shows that `ni` on the first `push` doesn't skip the rest of the function.  And that would be a super broken heuristic for some hand-written asm without source-line info, e.g. using `push` in a loop to build an array.

Comment: Thanks everyone the problem is solved solution is use of stepi instead of ni